# Extract min timestamp from string using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query the minimum datetime from a column that is stored as `nvarchar(max)`. There a a few tricky things with this query (at least for me)

- There is more than just the date being stored within each record.
- The position of the datetime is relative - although it does always appear in the format `**(DD-MM-YY at HH:MM PM`
- There are multiple datetimes stored in each record - so not only do I need to locate and capture where there is a datetime, I need to find the minimum datetime within the record
- I can't just change the format that the data is stored in - there is over a decade of information that is stored this way.

The column is called 'hdresp' - here is sample data:

> > **(03-Apr-14 at 09:44 AM email sent) -- Billy Bob: Upgrade ordered. **(02-Apr-14 at 04:16 PM email sent) -- Sammy Richards: I can give you another cable to if you think that will help but it just might be time for an upgrade. If you want to go that route I have to ask that you submit another request for New Hardware. **(02-Apr-14 at 03:17 PM email sent) -- Paul Smith: Michael Stop by my desk when you have a second.

- What I would like to end up with is a query that identifies `02-Apr-14 at 3:17 PM` as the minimum time and converts it to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` - for example `2014-04-02 15:17:00`

Comment: you can locate the date/time pattern very easily using PATINDEX function. However, in order to locate a few of them in a single record you will have to use a function

Comment: If you can assume that the first found pattern is the smallest (i.e. it is the first email in the email chain) then you can do it using a simple Update SQL using PATINDEX function

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response! Isn't the PATINDEX function just going to return the position of the datetime occurrence instead of the actual values?

Comment: Yes, it will. Now, have a look at SUBSTRING function. Use the value from PATINDEX as a Start position and `21` as length

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help. I've been trying a combination SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX all day and made little to no progress. Your method is definitely on the right track. The first matching pattern is actually the largest datetime instead of the smallest.

Comment: You can apply PATINDEX to the string reversed using `REVERSE`. This will give you the position of the pattern (PTTERM must be reversed as well). Once you find the position, just use `LEN` - <the found position> to locate the position of the pattern from the normal string. It is a bit tricky, but doable. If you provide an SQL you have already tried we will be able to tidy it up

Comment: This is what I am currently working with-

select substring(hdresp,patindex ('**(%', hdresp), 21) AS 'Update Time'
from tblhdmain
where hdindex = 211458

Comment: To make it really fool-proof your pattern should be more specific: `patindex('**([%][0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][a-z][a-z]-[0-9][0-9] at [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M email sent)')`. If applied to a REVERSEd string the pattern should be reversed as well

Comment: I'm trying this here but I'm getting an error. Can you help with final tweaking?

select reverse(substring(reverse (hdresp), reverse( patindex('**(%%[0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][a-z][a-z]-[0-9][0-9] at [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M email sent)', reverse (hdresp)), 21)) AS 'Update Time'
from tblhdmain
where hdindex = 211458

Comment: REVERSE should be applied to the pattern: select reverse(substring(reverse (hdresp), patindex(reverse( '**(%%[0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][a-z][a-z]-[0-9][0-9] at [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M email sent))', reverse (hdresp), 21))

Comment: Lesson: "There are multiple datetimes stored in each record" indicates poor relational database design. The data should have been parsed and broken into rows and columns before it was stored.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try this approach:

```
select hdresp, min(ts) as timestamp
from (
  select hdresp, cast(substring(hdresp,delta+3,10)+substring(hdresp,delta+15,9) as datetime2) as ts
  from (
    select 
      hdresp,
      charindex('**(',hdresp,1) as delta
    from problem
  union
    select 
      hdresp,
      charindex('**(',hdresp,1+charindex('**(',hdresp,1)) as delta
    from problem
  union
    select 
      hdresp,
      charindex('**(',hdresp,1+charindex('**(',hdresp,1+charindex('**(',hdresp,1))) as delta
    from problem
  union
    select 
      hdresp,
      charindex('**(',hdresp,1+charindex('**(',hdresp,1+charindex('**(',hdresp,1+charindex('**(',hdresp,1)))) as delta
    from problem
  ) as temp1
  where delta > 0
) as temp2
group by hdresp
;
```

See example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1a99/1
If there are more than 4 possible timestamps in a hdresp, just add more `UNION SELECT...` sections.

Comment: I like that approach. There is the possibility of more than 4 responses though. There isn't a limit to the number of possible responses. I'm afraid that just adding more UNION SELECT statements will slow the query.

Comment: You could run a query to find the maximum number, then amend the SQL as I mentioned, to add more `UNION SELECT...` sections. I realize this is clunky, but SQL Server doesn't make it easy. See the updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30135/1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help!

I ended up using this to extract and convert the minimum time from a string:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, REPLACE(LEFT(RIGHT(hdresp, PATINDEX('%(**%', REVERSE(hdresp)) - 1), 21), 'at ', ''))
from tblhdmain
where hdindex = 211458
```

Which gave me the result:

```
2014-04-02 15:17:00.000
```